# Perforce Diff -- how do you see a diff of the current file and a specific changelist revision?

Tags: diff, perforce, changelist

I'm trying to diff a current file against a specific CL# in another branch. I can see if I check manually that the changes are in-fact there. However, sometimes this requires multiple steps (starting at baseline, checking the next integration (maybe test), going there, checking the next integration (maybe production), etc. until I end up at the branch I'm checking).

What I assumed I could do is just find the file in the branch I'm checking and diff that file against the CL# that made the original change.

Example:

- File `supbro.cpp` was changed with `CL: 1122` in `//sup/baseline/branch/init`
- I want to check `../branch/test` for these changes on `supbro.cpp`
- I select the file in `../branch/test` and click `Diff Against..` 
  [image]

When I attempt to do this, I still see the diff .. i.e., I see the changes that were originally made. What I ***expected*** to see was no diffs, indicating that the two files / CLs were identical.

What am I missing?
*disclaimer*: I'm pretty new to p4

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried diffing these files on the command line to see if they are identical? For example:

```
  p4 diff2 //sup/baseline/branch/init/supbro.cpp@1122 //sup/baseline/branch/test/supbro.cpp#head
```

EXAMPLES

```
$ p4 diff2 -q //pb/main/src/yyacc //depot/Jam/MAIN/src/yyacc@263
==== //pb/main/src/yyacc#1 (xtext) - //depot/Jam/MAIN/src/yyacc#3 (text) ==== content

$ p4 diff2 //pb/main/src/yyacc@8703 //depot/Jam/MAIN/src/yyacc
==== //pb/main/src/yyacc#1 (xtext) - //depot/Jam/MAIN/src/yyacc#5 (xtext) ==== identical
```

RERENCES

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_diff2.html